# I want to replace a character in 6th column of a UNIX file which seems bit challenging

Tags: linux, unix

I have a CSV file which contain's 9 fields in it and more number of lines. I want to replace " to "" in 6th field except the last and first " all inside it should be replaced from " to ""

please find below example input and output files

## Input

"MCDW","6HV-00014","CDW CORPORATION","A931216","","INSTALL WALL MOUNT PPI DISPLAY UP TO 55" bsgdf","08/28/2018","20180830212807",""

## Output

"MCDW","6HV-00014","CDW CORPORATION","A931216","","INSTALL WALL MOUNT PPI DISPLAY UP TO 55"" bsgdf","08/28/2018","20180830212807",""

Comment: INPUT has `TO 55"` while OUTPUT has `TO 55""` (extra `"`). Is that the only difference? The requirement is still unclear, though.

Comment: Is it ensured that the commas separate the columns and there are no additional commas within the quotes?
And is it ensured that each column is surrounded by quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using perl. First, I'm replacing the all double quotes to two times of it in the 6th column using the hex character \x22. Second, I'm checking if the 
first and last character ends with double quotes. If so, they are removed. I Added two more records by modifying the 6th column to show that it works. See the code below.

```
> cat 6th_column.dat
"MCDW","6HV-00014","CDW CORPORATION","A931216","","INSTALL WALL MOUNT PPI DISPLAY UP TO 55" bsgdf","08/28/2018","20180830212807",""
"MCDW2","6HV-00014","CDW CORPORATION","A931216","",INSTALL WALL MOUNT PPI DISPLAY UP TO 55" bsgdf,"08/28/2018","20180830212807",""
"MCDW3","6HV-00014","CDW CORPORATION","A931216","","INSTALL WALL MOUNT PPI DISPLAY "UP TO 55" bsgdf","08/28/2018","20180830212807",""
"MCDW3","6HV-00014","CDW CORPORATION","A931216","",INSTALL WALL MOUNT PPI DISPLAY "UP TO 55" bsgdf,"08/28/2018","20180830212807",""
>
> perl -a -F, -ne  ' $x=${F[5]}; $x=~s/\x22/\x22\x22/g;$x=~s/^\x22//g;$x=~s/\x22$//g;  print "$F[0],$x\n" ' 6th_column.dat
"MCDW","INSTALL WALL MOUNT PPI DISPLAY UP TO 55"" bsgdf"
"MCDW2",INSTALL WALL MOUNT PPI DISPLAY UP TO 55"" bsgdf
"MCDW3","INSTALL WALL MOUNT PPI DISPLAY ""UP TO 55"" bsgdf"
"MCDW3",INSTALL WALL MOUNT PPI DISPLAY ""UP TO 55"" bsgdf
>
```

let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal fix - doubling the quote character in that particular spot in your test input - is easy enough with something `sed`, or just about any other tool that can do basic search/replace:

```
$ sed 's/55" bsgdf/55"" bsgdf/' file.in > file.out
```

This assumes that the file `file.in` contains the line in question, and that the pattern `55" bsgdf` only appears in that one spot where an update is needed.

**Is your real problem actually more general?**

A common convention for files in CSV format is to quote values using the quote character ", and when a quote character is part of a value, double it - i.e., use "" - to encode it.

For example, to encode values:

- New York, New York
- $179.98
- Special rate "$149.99"

the line in a CSV file would look like:

```
"New York, New York","$179.98","Special rate ""$149.99"""
```

But it's pretty easy to create broken CSV files by naively emitting lines like:

```
"<val1>","<val2>",...,"<valN>"
```

...for values that include quote characters, but forgetting to escape/double the quotes in those values. The above example would be emitted wrongly as:

```
"New York, New York","$179.98","Special rate "$149.99""
```

Seems to me that you are dealing with files that have this last problem.

It's often possible to fix up such messes, although a general solution is impossible (consider the issue you face if some single values look like `"a","b","c"`).

But if your data does not include such problem cases, consider something like the following. It's pretty crude, transforming CSV into unquoted pipe-delimited text data, doubling surviving quote characters, then transforming pipe-delimited back to CSV. If your data does naturally include the pipe character `|` you'll need to use some other intermediate delimiter.

```
#!/bin/sh

# sed commands (-e <cmd>)
#
#  delete leading "
#  delete trailing "
#  replace all "," sequences with |
#  replace all " chars with ""
#  return all | chars to ","
#  append trailing "
#  prepend leading "
#
# Assumes that the pipe character '|' is not part of data

sed  \
  -e 's/^"//'     \
  -e 's/"$//'     \
  -e 's/","/|/g'  \
  -e 's/"/""/g'   \
  -e 's/|/","/g'  \
  -e 's/$/"/'     \
  -e 's/^/"/'
```

Save the above as, say, `double_quotes.sh`, make the file executable, and use via something like:

```
$ ./double_quotes.sh < file.in > file.out
```

The above shares some notions with the `perl`-based answer from @stack0114106 : namely, the use of a sequence of substituion steps, applied in order. Such sequences are often painful to read and understand, but are a staple of these kinds of tools.